# How can I connect to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I´m tryng to connect to MySQL Database with SpringBoot, but I got this error below:

Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Dev/Repositorios/jira-quality/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/jboscod/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.21/mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/jboscod/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar

Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application-desenv.yml'

My pom is this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>br.com.oss.jira.quality</groupId>
<artifactId>jira-quality</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jira-quality</name>
<description>Gerenciador de inconsistências no Jira</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.6</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>  -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
               <!-- Exclude the default Jackson dependency -->
<!--            <exclusions> -->
<!--                <exclusion> -->
<!--                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId> -->
<!--                </exclusion> -->
<!--            </exclusions> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>desenv</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>desenv</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

</project>
```

And my application.properties is below:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jiraquality

spring.datasource.username = root

spring.datasource.password = admin

spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I don´t know if the problem is in my pom or my application file.

Comment: That is not a format of YML file, chang file name to application.properties

Comment: I changed, but the error continues.

Comment: try change spring.datasource.driver-class-name to spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver if you use mysql-connector-java version 8

Comment: In which location you are maintaining this property file, I guess from this error,
Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application-desenv.yml'

It is not able to find the property file in class path.

Comment: I found out that the problem to load the application-desenv was the missing ":". I have to replace "=" for ":", and worked. But now, it appears another problem. "java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora Padr�o de Buenos Aires' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support."

Comment: This: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jiraquality?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application-desenv.yml'`

Have you try to change your `application.properties` to `application-desenv.yml`?

Comment: I have an application.yml as application father, and two childrens (application-desenv.yml and application-prod.yml. I got to connect to hsqldb, but I can´t to connect to MySQL.

Comment: Try to use @PropertySource to specify your properties or yml

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add Spring Data JPA on you pom file add this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


  
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Clean your project and take Maven update.
It will be working successfully.

Comment: Can you show your complete Pom file here or Try Remove this MySql Version  <version>8.0.21</version> add update like my answer...

Comment: Ok, it´s above.

Comment: Need I put some hibernate dependency?

Comment: not necessary It is done by JPA. 
You can take help from below git link if you need it.

https://github.com/imrangthub/SpringBootThymeleftSpringSecurityAppWithJpaProvider